# Xbap, xaml browser application (Clickonce), Application Download Error

Tags: clickonce, xbap

I have a big question, I developed a clickonce application and hosted on IIS with correct certificate (I have no certificate error in IE). I am able to run https on my localhost but if I try to access it by using Ip address i get "Application Download Error". I've spent like 2 weeks trying to figure it out, but no luck :-(
If I expand, I get

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* An exception occurred while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading https://xx.xx.xx.xx/testxbap/testxbap.xbap did not succeed.
    + The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
    + Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    + An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Anyone can help. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is accessing the xbap outside my server. Note that on http it works well, but no luck on https outside the server.

Comment: After several days of research, The problem was **bad certificates** I was generating from my Active Directory Certificate Authority. I generated new self-signed certificates and the problem was solved.